# Call to undefined function Â ()

Tags: php, laravel

I were using laravel this wonderful evening when I stumpled upon this strange error that frankly I've never seen before. I am simply looping through some arrays and trying to print out some values in a view file.

The error:

```
Unhandled Exception

Message:

Error rendering view: [controller.index]

Call to undefined function Â ()
Location:

/web/storage/views/7b064aafcdba902ea2c593167b6df491 on line 4
```

The code:

```
@section('content')
    <?php $i = 0; $current = 0 ?>
    @foreach($data as $date => $episodes)
        @if($i == 0 || ($i % 5 == 7 && $i == $current + 1))
            <tr>
            <?php $current = $i; ?>
        @endif

        @foreach($data as $day)
            <td>
                @foreach($day as $episode)
                    {{ $episode->title }}
                @endforeach
            </td>
        @endforeach


        @if($i % 5 == 7 && $i == $current + 7)
            <tr>
            <?php $current = $i; ?>
        @endif
        <?php $i++; ?>
    @endforeach
@endsection
```

And the compiled version:

```
<?php \Laravel\Section::start('content'); ?>
    <?php $i = 0; $current = 0 ?>
    <?php foreach($data as $date => $episodes): ?>
        <?php if($i == 0 || ($i % 5 == 7 && $i == $current + 1)): ?>
            <tr>
            <?php $current = $i; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php foreach($data as $day): ?>
            <td>
                <?php foreach($day as $episode): ?>
                    <?php echo  $episode->title ; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>


        <?php if($i % 5 == 7 && $i == $current + 7): ?>
            <tr>
            <?php $current = $i; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php $i++; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php \Laravel\Section::stop(); ?>
```

It might be an easy solution but I can't find any good results on Google. Help me understand this error! :)

Comment: This looks likes a template ... you can't continue to suppress PHP errors this way

Comment: You should show us the template file `7b064aafcdba902ea2c593167b6df491` if you can recover it (and it contains the converted php code, that is). Otherwise file a bug report for Laravel, as this error message is kinda useless.

Comment: Looks like an encoding error, but the compiled template will tell more...

Comment: It is a template, sorry I'm kind of new to Laravel. The template file is encoded with UTF-8 so it should be no probs.. http://pastie.org/5054845

Comment: Removed all the extra `;` but it didnt help much

Comment: Tried to save it as UTF-8 with BOM and ISO-8859-1 and then the Â disappeared but the error stays the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The space you removed is *not a space*. It is actually a **non-breaking space** (U+00A0). The giveaway is the "Â", which appears as the first byte of characters between U+0080 and U+00BF inclusive when encoded as UTF-8 but misinterpreted as Latin-1. For some reason the PHP compiler doesn't consider it to be whitespace and therefore tries to use it as a normal identifier.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the clarification. I must have slipped alt+space on my macbook. Strangest thing is that it didn't show up in neither Sublime Text 2 or Smultron when displaying hidden characters, only Coda was able to identify the problem.

Comment: @cubsink, man, thank you! This has been driving me nuts for MONTHS! I had no idea that I was even typing ALT-SPACE half the time, and it doesn't show up any different in almost every program. Apple should really vehemently warn every developer about the ALT-SPACE, uh "functionality".  I love my mac, but sometimes I really hate the way they do things.  I wish I could +1000 that comment.

Comment: Your welcome, but it was Ignacio who resolved the issue for me :P

Answer (score 0):

This obviously was an encoding problem, how it ever came to be is a big question tho (as I only work in UTF-8).

[image: Encoding problem]

Removed the space (^) after the OR-statement ( || ) and now it works flawlessly.